# How to identify all species observed in each cell of a research grid

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, species

I have created a grid map as a shapefile. I have added a point layer that includes “species name”, coordinates and etc. I put a part of it below.
[image]

Now, My problem is, when I use “count points in polygon” tool, the “species name” is missed and I cant see the “species name” in the attribute table. This tool counts the number of points only such as this:
Left        bottom    right        top        number of point
[image]

If I want to ask my question in another way, How to export the species names which fall into each cell.  It is very important for us to know what species are inside each cell.
[image]

Comment: Base on the left, bottom, top and right columns in your t5 layer, shown in the join results above, it looks like you have created a research grid using longitude and latitude intervals. This means the cells in your research grid are not equal areas, if that matters for how you are going to use your data.

Answer (score 4):

On the grid layer, create a new attribute with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and the following expression. It generates you a text field for each grid cell, listing the species that are located in this cell.

Be sure to set `Output field type` to `Text (string)` and set an `Output field length` long enough to fit the whole list.

```
array_to_string (
     array_distinct( 
        overlay_contains( 
            'layer_species',  -- adapt the layer name
            "species"  -- adapt the name of the attribute
        )
    )
)
```

*The expression used as a dynamic label: the black labels indicate which species (red dots with red labels) are inside each cell. Duplicates are removed to get just a list of the names of species that appear inside the cell:*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this:

1. First run *Join Attributes by Location* (vector menu>Data Management Tools) - this will create a memory layer called **Joined Layer**.
2. Then save **Joined Layer** as a geopackage. In the screenshot below it is called **points_by_grid**
3. Connect to the new geopackage using the DB Manager and use a sql expression like this:
   [image]

Comment: Thank You...
it is solved by this way.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it using the checkmark to the left. It is a way of thanking @Aquamarine by awarding them reputation and it will help future readers of your question.